# azure function to listen to any service bus topic/subscription

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

Using the template to create a azure function, one can create function only listening to particular pair of azure topic/subscription:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mySbMsg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "ftopic1",
      "subscriptionName": "mysub",
      "connection": "collosysazfuncsb_RootManageSharedAccessKey_SERVICEBUS",
      "accessRights": "Manage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

and then in run.csx you just receive the message

```
public static void Run(string message, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"message: {message}");
}
```

Is there a way to listen to any topic/subscription using azure function and then receive topicName & subscriptionName as parameters in `Run` method.

Doing topic-name as * does not help, and also it does not provide topic-name in `Run`.

Comment: Azure Service Bus (ASB) didn't allow for subscribers to subscribe more than one topic at a time. In other words, the ASB doesn't have a topic-based wildcards like for example the IBM WebSphere MQ. However, the ASB has a feature known as auto-forwarding, where the messages can be forwarded within the same namespace from any topics to any one based on the filter, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Functions only allows to listen to a single queue or subscription. It doesn't allow to listen to multiple entities (queues or subscriptions) as the Azure Service Bus client doesn't support this. Instead, as it [was pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766882/azure-function-to-listen-to-any-service-bus-topic-subscription#comment84539026_48766882), you could leverage [Auto Forwarding feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding) of Azure Service Bus. The broker will forward any messages to the destination topic/queue and you'll have a single queue for Azure Function to feed of.

It's important to note that auto forwarded messages will not carry any information that would allow to identify from what queue/subscription they have originated. This is only possible with [dead-lettered messages](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/centralized-dead-letter-queue-with-azure-service-bus).

Since you're interested in topics, you could "workaround" this issue by having an action on the rules of your subscriptions that would stampt messages with a custom property. For example, having 3 topics with default subscription each and a default filter with rule action

`set [x-source] = 'topic-N'`

where `N` is a topic identifier, would cause all auto forwarded messages to contain `x-source` custom property with value corresponding to the topic they have originated from.

Comment: great, thanks for the workaround :), does the logic apps also behave the same way, I mean, logic app triggers only on particular subscription??

Comment: Believe it does. It's the same broker LogicApps had to talk to.